# Use a Java enum with an object method

Tags: java, enums

I'm pretty new to Java and following a course for it. So here goes my super stupid question probably. Suppose I have class with an `enum` like this:

```
public class Diamant implements Comparable<Diamant> {

    final private String stockNr;
    final private double karaat;
    final private String helderheid;
    final private char kleur;
    final private String snede;

    public Diamant(String stockNr, double karaat, String helderheid, char kleur, String cut) {
        this.stockNr = stockNr;
        this.karaat = karaat;
        this.helderheid = helderheid;
        this.kleur = kleur;
        this.snede = cut;
    }

    public String getStockNummer() {
        return stockNr;
    }

    public double getKaraat() {
        return karaat;
    }

    public String getHelderheid() {
        return helderheid;
    }

    public char getKleur() {
        return kleur;
    }

    public String getSnede() {
        return snede;
    }

    enum Color {
        D(0), E(1), F(2), G(3), H(4), I(5), J(6), K(7), L(8), M(9), N(10), O(11),
        P(12), Q(13), R(14), S(15), T(16), U(17), V(18), W(19), X(20), Y(21), Z(22);

        int quality;

        Color(int quality) {
            this.quality = quality;
        }

        public int getQuality() {
            return quality;
        }
    }

    enum Brightness {
        FL(0), IF(1), VVS1(2), VVS2(3), VS1(4), VS2(5), SI1(6), SI2(7), I1(8), I2(9), I3(10);

        int quality;

        Brightness(int quality) {
            this.quality = quality;
        }

        public int getQuality() {
            return quality;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StockNr='" + getStockNummer() + "\t" +
                " Karaat=" + getKaraat() + "\t" +
                " Helderheid='" + getHelderheid() + "\t" +
                " Kleur=" + getKleur() + "\t";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Diamant other) {
        //Sort according to Karaat (Max=5.0)
        if (this.getKaraat() < other.getKaraat()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.getKaraat() > other.getKaraat()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            // Sort according to Kleur first then Helderheid
            Color.D.getQuality();

            (this.getKleur()).getQuality();

            if (this.getKleur() < other.getKleur()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (this.getKleur() > other.getKleur()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

How is it possible to use the method `getQuality` without explicitly typing the `enum` value in the `CompareTo`. In other words, this works fine:

```
Color.D.getQuality();
```

However, this doesn't work (although the method `getKleur` returns `D` to):

```
Color.(this.getKleur()).getQuality();
```

How can I work with the `enum` method `getQuality()` without hard typing the letter?

Comment: `this.getKleur().getQuality()` (I'm assuming `this.getKleur()` returns a `Color`)

Comment: you say `getKleur` returns `D`, but is it a `Color.D` or a `"D"` `String` ?

Comment: why not store the color in the diamond instead of a character?

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept!

Comment: I suggest you should be consistent in your language. Your variable names are in Dutch, whereas your enum types are English. You should choose one of either, and use that. My personal preference is English, since it'll make your code more portable.

Comment: I totally agree, but it was a task for school and the teacher tends to use Dutch while I am more inclined to code in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
class YourClass { 
  Color getColor() { return Color.D; }
```

...

```
YourClass thingy = new YourClass(...
System.out.println(thingy.getColor().getQuality());
```

Explanation: `Color` is a valid return type; and a method defined to return `Color` can return any instance of that Enum. Which can then be used ... well, as you would expect it to use.

Given your comment:

```
final private char kleur;
```

is obviously "wrong". The point of an enum is ... to be an enum. The fact that all enum constants are *single characters* doesn't magically make

```
char klear = D;
```

a valid assignment. Thus the obvious answer is to change that code to

```
final private Color kleur;
```

And please note: if you need that "stringified" representation, you can always do

```
Color whatever = Color.D;
System.out.println(whatever.name());
```

for example (the above would print "D").

Comment: Added the class to the OP

Comment: Awesome! Your answer is the most correct I believe. Change the `return type` of `kleur` to be `Color` will always make sure that the `enum` will function properly. I just didn't know that the name of the `enum` was immediately a type I could use. Thank you, still have a long way to go.

Comment: And please see my other comment on the other answer: I would go one step further and rename those enum constants. D, E, F are names that dont "mean" anything. To the contrary: it is just confusing beyond limits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Color.valueOf(String.valueOf(this.getKleur())).getQuality();
```

Comment: Thx, but it complains that `getKleur` returns a `char` which cannot be converted to `String` for the `enum` to be used.

Comment: Added the proper call to the OP

Comment: Yes, your updated answer works 100% fine. Thank you :)

Comment: But please note: the above "solution" is taking away the compile-time safety benefit of using an Enum. If you decide to use an Enum, then use that enum in your source code, not single chars! You know have to remember that these chars have those special meaning; and on the other hand, you have to remember that all your enum constants must stay single chars (what is a rather **bad** idea in the first place). What is a name like D or S or X telling you about a Color? Meaning: @DarkLite1  please consider fixing your broken design; instead of solving its "symptoms" with a solution like this!

Answer (score 0):

this.getKleur() returns a character, not the instances of Color enum , that's why Color.(this.getKleur()).getQuality(); doesn't work.
You need to take a roundabout approach here:

```
Color.valueOf(Character.toString(this.getKleur())).getQuality();
```

Comment: Thx, is your way of casting better than Jerry06's?

Comment: No, its just another way of converting character to string.